# GET request variable in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

for my page

```
www.domain.com/page.php?x=1&y=2&z=3
```

how can i set the `$_GET` variables inside the AJAX `$.get()`?

```
$.get('page.php',
{x: x, y: y, z: z},
function(){
})
```

how do i define the `$_GET` using `jQuery` or `JavaScript`?
i can have `1 2 3` and `4 5 6` and `7 8 9`

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45019951/edit) with a properly detailed explanation of your problem or what it is that you are trying to acheive

Comment: for the data part, like `var x = $_GET['x'];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js) and [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html)):

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
var x = getUrlParameter('x');
var y = getUrlParameter('y');
```

**EDIT:** Or if you also use PHP for this site you could just do:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['x']); ?>
```

Comment: Well, PHP seems the quickest solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can assing the value at a var  or assign directly

```
var x = 10;
var y = 100;
var z = 1000;
$.get('page.php',
  {x: x, y: y, z: z},
   function(){
 })
```

or

```
$.get('page.php',
  {x: 10, y: 100, z: 1000},
   function(){
 })
```

Comment: there is no dynamic variable in JS or JQuery? like `$_GET[]`?

Comment: $_GET is used  by php

Comment: Yes, in PHP, and i thought if JS or JQuery has the same functionality

Comment: JS and Jquery are client-side languages, they don't have any knowledge of the initial request. They can just parse the URL.

Comment: No  .. as suggested  by puelo ... the client side have not this knowledge

Answer (score 0):

As [puelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386873/puelo) already answered. you have to extract the parameters from the url

I'm just adding a reminder that you can get the url of the ajax request -not the url of the current document- like this

```
$.get('page.php',
    {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3},
    function(data){
        console.log(this.url);
    }
);
```

this will log

`page.php?x=1&y=2&z=3`

which you can extract the parameters from later